# inner product over two functions

Tags: polynomials, fourier-series, inner-products, intuition

in class we learned about the inner product of two functions as $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx$ but I failed to get an intuition about what it means, can someone please explain it to me?

also what the norm $\|f(x)\|_2=\sqrt{\int_a^b f^2(x) dx}$ means I can't understand what means that a function has a norm / length / magnitude ?
please give me some intuition for these concepts or a way to think about them ?

Comment: On a vector space, you can consider an inner product (think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard dot product. These give you a way to measure the length of a vector (here given by $||f(x)||_2$) and more things that inner products let you do (such as Gram-Schmidt, talking about orthogonal diagonalization etc.

Comment: Specifically this is a very close analogy to the standard dot product. Let's say $a = 0$ and $b = 100$. Let $\mathbf u \in \Bbb R^{100}$ be a vector with $100$ components. You can plot the components of $\mathbf u$ as a sort of bar graph, or think of it as a function $\{1, \dotsc, 100\} \to \Bbb R$. The dot product is what you get by adding up the products of the "height" of each component. This inner product you have just generalises this to when you have vectors with "infinitely many components", ie functions from $\Bbb R$, in which case the sum becomes an integral.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a^b |f(x)| dx$ is the area between the axis $y=0$ and the graph of the function $|f|$.

$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx$ is the area between the axis $y=0$ and the graph of $f^2$.

$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx$ is the algeabric area between the axis $y = 0$ and the graph of $fg$, 'algeabric' in the sens that area above the axis $y = 0$ is counted positively and area below the axis $y = 0$ is counted negatively.

It turns out that we can use these notions to define a norm and an inner product on spaces of functions.

The norm-2 is particularly important because it is an euclidian norm, meaning that it is induced by an inner product ( $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx$ ). You can therefore have various notions such as orthogonality for functions.

Does that help?

Comment: its in the right direction, basically we are trying compare "lengths" of functions by their integral ? can you expand on orthogonality of functions and what means that the norm is a finite number ?

Comment: More or less yes. We need a notion of distance between functions. But there are infinitely many different ways to do this. For instance, on the space $C([a,b])$, the formula $\| f\|_p = \left(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}$ defines a norm, for all $p \geq 1$. The case $p=2$ is extremely important because for the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ is associated to an inner product. This allows to measure angles between functions and to use a lot of very strong results on general inner product space.

Comment: actually I am trying to understand the norm with connection to Fourier series so actually what that means that for a given Fourier series the norm of the Fourier series for a function f is equal to the norm of  the function f? if you can make this connection clear to that would be awesome

Comment: Basically the Fourier series of a function is just its decomposition $f = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n(f) e_n$ in the orthogonal (infinite) basis $\{e_n : x \mapsto e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{T} n} \}$ of the function space (there might be a normalization constant in front of these functions but the idea is the same). So the equality $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \|c_n(f) e_n \|^2 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |c_n(f)|^2$ is just a generalization of Pythagor theorem. Does that help you?

Comment: I would you like you to explain more, its critical point that I want to understand , because its mot that clear the connection, can you edit your comment with much richer details ?I will update the post accordingly

Comment: You can read this short Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity which explains it quite well I find (and probably better than I would)